# Value of React input component cannot be changed if "value" field is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material-UI for my React app.

I want to delete value inserted to input field by clicking another component.

The issue is that the `OutlinedInput` field works properly only when it does not have `value` property. In case it is added, the value from `value` is shown inside the `OutlinedInput` field and no another value can be inserted. However, I cannot delete the value of `OutlinedInput` by clicking another React component if `OutlinedInput` doesn't have `value` property.

```
const Search = (props: any) => {
  const searchedMovie = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.searchedMovie
  );
  const isMovieOpened = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.isMoviePageOpened
  );
  const dispatch: Dispatch<any> = useDispatch();
  let history = useHistory();
  
  const fetchMoviesList = (event: any) => {
    const searchedMovieValue = event.target.value;
    dispatch(changeSearchedMovie(searchedMovieValue));
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    if (isMovieOpened === true) {
      dispatch(isMoviePageOpened(false));
      history.push("/");
    }
  }

  const handleKeyPress = (event: any) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      fetchMoviesList(event);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (searchedMovie) {
      fetchSearchedMovie(searchedMovie)
        .then((res) => dispatch(addHomePageMovies(res)))
        .catch(() => dispatch(addHomePageMovies([])));
    } else {
      fetchMovies('1')
        .then((res) => dispatch(addHomePageMovies(res)))
        .catch(() => dispatch(addHomePageMovies([])));
    }
     // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [searchedMovie]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <OutlinedInput 
          color="secondary" 
          className="seach-field" 
          type="string"  
          onBlur={fetchMoviesList} 
          onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
          placeholder="Search" 
          />
    </>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, input components in react can follow two patterns: [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) or uncontrolled components.

In a controlled component, the parent stores the current value as state and provides it via a prop to the input component. It also provides an `onChange` handler to update the state on the parent whenever the value changes from the child.

In an uncontrolled component, the state is managed internally by the component.

Many components (including material UI's) offer the ability to be either controlled or uncontrolled, by allowing you to pass both or neither of `value`/`onChange`. Your current solution is a mix of both, which is a mistake.

You should add a `useState` hook to the `Search` component to store the input value (a `string`) and pass it to the [`OutlinedInput`](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/#props). You should also pass an `onChange` callback which sets this state to `event.target.value`.

Comment: Your answer is by far one of the most comprehensive and clear answers I've received in stackoverflow! Your suggested solution works, thanks!

Comment: You were providing the current `value` via a prop, which tells the input component you want it to be controlled. So, it sends out its changes via `onChange` - but you weren't responding to that change and updating the `value` prop. In summary, the `value` prop was following the controlled pattern, but the `onChange` prop following the uncontrolled pattern.